# Python can't read DDE linked datas on excel file

Tags: python, excel, android-livedata, dde, excel-reader

I have been developing a telegram bot to get some live data sent. Firstly, I get the dde link written on excel. Secondly, I get the data read. But xlwings, pandas, excel2img, any library can not read the datas correctly. I just can see either NaN or #N/A

I do not share the whole part because I think it is the important part. I can share more if necesarry.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Template.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
ws["E14"] = "=MTX|DATA!'USDSEK.SON'"
wb.save("Result.xlsx")
wb.close()

excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel('Result.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
print(excel_data_df)
 
wsheet = xw.Book("Result.xlsx").sheets['Sheet1']
v1 = wsheet.range("A14:F14").value

print("Result:", v1)
   
excel2img.export_img("Result.xlsx", "image.png", "Sheet1")
await update.message.reply_photo("image.png")
```

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g46X4.png)